# RestSharp: identifying JSON fields not in POCO

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp

I'm using `RestSharp` to call a REST API, and deserialize JSON to POCOs.  And for the most part, this is working really well.

The challenge I'm facing is that the API isn't fully documented.  It's primarily examples of returned JSON payloads for each endpoint. I've used those to construct the POCOs for those endpoints.

But the examples are somewhat unreliable.  Some of them show properties whose names make them sound like child objects, but the example just has the property set to `null`, so there's nothing to go on for a POCO.

Conversely, sometimes  properties I'm actually receiving aren't shown in the example, so if I hadn't been scrutinizing JSON by hand, I wouldn't have known to include them.

The first thing I did was contact the API vendor.  I asked for schemas, but they claim, somewhat improbably, not to have any.  The examples are all the documentation there is.  They don't have a developer forum.

Now ,`RestSharp` handles the "more data than you expected" situation reasonably elegantly, in that nothing blows up:

> Your classes define how you want the returned data to be deserialized.
>   Instead of traversing the data and searching for a matching property
>   in your class, RestSharp uses your class as the starting point,
>   looping through each publicly-accessible, writable property and
>   searching for a corresponding element in the data returned.

(Source: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization)

That's nice.  But what I want is to be notified - programmatically - when I am receiving data that the POCO can't capture. Then I could at least notify the operator that some more development needs to be done.

Is anyone aware of an extension or addition that does this?  I would rather not write my own deserializer just to add in this functionality.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25172403/restsharp-deserialize-json-object-with-less-more-fields-than-some-class) looks similar to mine, but looks like it refers to an earlier version of `RestSharp` that *did* blow up in this situation.  And since some of my POCOs map to relational database tables, which are the opposite of "flexible", the solution using `dynamics` won't meet my needs at all.

Comment: I know it is not your case but you can use *MissingMemberHandling* in Json.Net.

Comment: @L.B  Thanks.  I think a custom deserializer, or a helper class based on the deserializer logic, is my only option.  Unfortunately, the `JsonDeserializer`, though not sealed, isn't written with inheritance in mind.  All the core logic is in private methods.

Comment: Json.Net is the swiss army knife of json handling. If you want to go that route, you can ask another question,